# where can I find default inputrc/key-bindings config on macOsX?

Tags: macos, bash, readline

I know that I can add an .inputrc file in my home folder, but for studying purposes, I would like to see the default key-bindings (actually the default inputrc conf) used by my system.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Mac Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html):

The standard key bindings are specified in /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Resources/StandardKeyBinding.dict. These standard bindings include a large number of Emacs-compatible control key bindings, all the various arrow key bindings, bindings for making field editors and some keyboard UI work, and backstop bindings for many function keys.

To customize bindings, you create a file named DefaultKeyBinding.dict in ~/Library/KeyBindings/ and specify bindings to augment or replace the standard bindings. You may use the standard bindings file as a template. It is recommended that you use the Property List Editor application to edit a bindings dictionary. You may use another application such as TextEdit or Xcode, but if you do you must ensure the encoding of the saved file is UTF8.

Answer (score 2):

```
bind -P
```

and even better:

```
bind -p > .inputrc
```

was what I was looking for.